# Setup of MySQL Group Replication (Master-Master)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I'm about to start testing a master master setup using MySQL Group Replication.  I've set up 2 (so far) machines, likely will be a third.  They both have 2 nics, one for application access and one that has only LAN IP for inter-node communication.

I see in some docs where it mentions using two NICs, one for comm between nodes and one for comm with the apps. I'm at the point where I'm editing the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file.  I need to understand these settings:

Say my application nic has an ip of 10.3.0.4 and LAN only NIC has 10.3.1.4
Same setup on machine 2.

```
bind-address = "10.3.0.4"
report_host = "10.3.??" ??
loose-group_replication_local_address = "10.3.1.4:33061"
```

Which IP does the report host belong to?  I gather that the loose-group_replication_local_address is essentially another bind address but for the communication between nodes, but I can't find any examples of multi-nic setups that also deal with these settings.  All the tutorials that have these lines show putting the same ip due to only single nic.

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 in Azure

I'm following this guide for install:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04

The bit about dual nics comes from fragments of about 6 different pages.

EDIT:  @roothann straightened me out on what the report host is supposed to do. Now I have a new problemOnce mysql has been restarted, port 33061 doesn't show up in netstat, and I get this error in the logs: "Getting the peer name failed while connecting to server 10.3.1.5 with error 111 -Connection refused.  [GCS] Error on opening a connection to 10.3.1.5:33061 on local port: 33061. Error= 0"   Any ideas?  I HAVE added the group_replication plugin, but when I do this command:  mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION;
ERROR 3096 (HY000): The START GROUP_REPLICATION command failed as there was an error when initializing the group communication layer.

That's what made me check the logs and look at netstat.

ANOTHER EDIT:
As noted below, for some reason the secure install command didn't remove the directive to only take connections locally.  That's fixed.  New problem is that data wasn't syncing.  The second node took itself out of the group because it couldn't finish recovery.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| group_replication_applier | f0bcfc98-4255-11e8-b39f-000d3a1db637 | 10.3.1.4    |        3306 | ONLINE       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

So, for some reason, the replication is trying to happen on the LAN interfaces, but on the regular mysql port instead of 33061.  I tried to fix this, and I got this:

```
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PORT=33061, MASTER_PASSWORD='the password' FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';

ERROR 3139 (HY000): CHANGE MASTER with the given parameters cannot be performed on channel 'group_replication_recovery'.
```

EDIT May 17:
I rebuilt the cluster from scratch, this time with 3 machines.  Still same issue.  The first node comes up.  The additional two come up as well, but only show Recovering, then are removed from the cluster.

on first node, I get this in the log:

```
2018-05-17T14:37:21.859153Z 27 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.

+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| CHANNEL_NAME              | MEMBER_ID                            | MEMBER_HOST | MEMBER_PORT | MEMBER_STATE | MEMBER_ROLE | MEMBER_VERSION |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
| group_replication_applier | 38d4aa76-592f-11e8-814a-000d3a60e580 | 10.7.1.11   |       33061 | RECOVERING   | PRIMARY     | 8.0.11         |
| group_replication_applier | 3dbbb30f-592f-11e8-8fc7-000d3a603364 | 10.7.1.12   |       33061 | RECOVERING   | PRIMARY     | 8.0.11         |
| group_replication_applier | b0ff0148-592e-11e8-aa03-000d3a60e4cc | 10.7.1.10   |       33061 | ONLINE       | PRIMARY     | 8.0.11         |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I get this in logs from one of the other servers:

```
2018-05-17T14:57:17.970789Z 18 [ERROR] [MY-011583] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'For details please check performance_schema.replication_connection_status table and error log messages of Slave I/O for channel group_replication_recovery.'
2018-05-17T14:58:18.023898Z 18 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='10.7.1.10', master_port= 33061, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='10.7.1.10', master_port= 33061, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
```

I'm noticing that on the first node, the master_host variable is empty, while on the second, it's filled in with the primary's ip.  Now, since they're all supposed to be master, shouldn't the primary have something as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: report_host is a string that you just define as you like. Are you talking about InnoDB Cluster from GA 5.7 ? If so, are you using mysqlsh to bootstrap?

Comment: @roothahn I'm not sure, I'm just following that tutorial, it didn't say anything about innodb specifically.  Also, I don't think report_host is random.  It has to be either the ip for the bind address or the rep local address.  I'm trying to figure out which.

Comment: I didn't say it's random (it should not change, to be clear), but a string that you define, usually the Hostname or IP of the slave (so that you can identify it via SHOW SLAVE HOSTS on the master). But if you define a string or an alias which is not the hostname it's alright too. It's not related to the bind_address

Comment: @roothahn ok, that made more sense.  I went with the IP of the LAN-only nic, since that's how the nodes talk to each other.  New problem, and I'll edit the main post as well, is that when mysql has been restarted, port 33061 doesn't show up in netstat, and I get this error: "Getting the peer name failed while connecting to server 10.3.1.5 with error 111 -Connection refused.  [GCS] Error on opening a connection to 10.3.1.5:33061 on local port: 33061. Error= 0"   Any ideas?

Comment: maybe your my.cnf is missing the value for loose-group_replication_group_seeds. (comma-separated list of ip:port combinations of all nodes in the cluster). that's the point where I defined 13306

Comment: I found the issue.  in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf   Even though when I did the mysql_secure_installation and told it NOT to refuse remote conenctions, the line where it binds to 127.0.0.1 was still there, uncommented.  I commented it out, and voila, the START REPLICATION command works.  It's always the small stupid things :P

Comment: Ok, so group rep started.  New problem:  data isn't replicating. In the logs I get this:  [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'group_replication_recovery': error connecting to master 'repl@10.3.1.4:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2003.  For some reason, it's trying to connect on the LAN network on the standard mysql port instead of 33061.   So second node is stuck in Recovering.

Comment: @roothahn I've updated the main question to provide more info

Comment: why is there only one member in the group replication members list? unfortunately I don't really know how mysqlsh internally does the addInstance() , but it seems the other 2 required nodes are not yet a member of the gcs cluster

Comment: @roothahn I add the second one, it hangs at "Recovering", then gets removed from the group.  There's no indication of why in the logs.  I also posted this on the dbadmin forum with more clear info:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205460/mysql-group-replication-stuck-on-recovering

Comment: but where's the third node?

Comment: @roothahn I don't have a third node set up yet.  Is that an issue?  I'm planning a third, but I didn't want to have to pay for it until I can get this running.  Would not having a third cause this issue?

Comment: afaik GCS is a cluster-like replication, so three nodes are mandatory. At least that's the case for InnoDB cluster which is basically GCS, but I'm not an expert

Comment: @roothahn Hi, I was busy with a priority thing.  So, I redid the entire thing from scratch to eliminate any possible config issue.  I now have 3 machines in the cluster, still same issue.  The additional two nodes refuse to recover.  They are all listed as master, which is what i want.  I also did correct the transaction mismatch on all 3, so now they have the same gtid-next.  I'm going to edit more above as I'm running out of room in this comment.